# linux top -Hp [PID] show Node process has 4 node thread and 4 v8 worker thread

Tags: linux, node.js, multithreading, v8

I learned from other articles that node js is single thread, but when I run node on my server, I found it has 4 additional node thread and 4 V8 worker thread.

I want to know why. what's the responsibility of all these thread?

Can anyone provide some useful documents or some explaination?

my actions :

- start my node program.
- `ps aux |grep xxx` to find the pid
- use `top -Hp [the pid]` to show the thread of node process

[screen shot of top -Hp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8coI.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I infer frome node source code that the node js process has two type of tread pool:

1. libuv thread pool. Thread name is same as node process. It execute the task about I/O operation.
2. V8 WorkerThread pool. These thread do some background works, such as [GC](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/v8/src/heap/mark-compact.cc#L481), [complie optimizing](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/v8/src/compiler-dispatcher/optimizing-compile-dispatcher.cc#L194), I guess. The [default pool size](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node.cc#L145) is 4. You can run node with option `--v8-pool-size=N` to change it and use `top -Hp` to view it.

[v8-platform.h](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/v8/include/v8-platform.h)  contains some cues about background thread and foreground thread.

If anyone has ideas, welcome to improve this answer.

Comment: Do you have any sort of documentation to back this claim?